# Is it possible to use `locator()` with plots generated by sf?

Tags: r, r-sf

I was wondering if it's possible to use the `locator()` function to create new points with plots generated by `plot.sf`. I'm sorry but I don't know how to create a reproducible example, so I will do my best to explain my problem.

When I run the following code (clicking, for example, on the centroid of some non-blue regions), the `locator()` returns the coordinates of the selected points. They have a reasonable value. However, when I plot them, the results are not that accurate (i.e. none of the chosen point lie in the selected region). Can you explain to me what's the problem?

```r
library(sf)

nc = st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
plot(nc["SID74"], reset = FALSE)

pts <- locator()
pts <- st_sfc(st_multipoint(do.call(cbind, pts)), crs = st_crs(nc))
plot(pts, add = TRUE, pch = 16)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem; I don't have an answer but I suspect that the issue will be environment related.

I ran your code on Linux (with a small adjustment for target number of points / clicks) and the code behaves as expected. I was able to place three points inside the Mecklenburg (as in [Charlotte of Mecklenburg-Strelitz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charlotte_of_Mecklenburg-Strelitz)) county.

As `locator()` seems to use X11 (which is in my case native, but on Windows wrapped in a kind of convoluted fashion) I speculate that your problem may be environment related.

```
library(sf)

nc = st_read(system.file("gpkg/nc.gpkg", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)
plot(nc["SID74"], reset = FALSE)

pts <- locator(n = 3) # to speed up the process
pts <- st_sfc(st_multipoint(do.call(cbind, pts)), crs = st_crs(nc))
plot(pts, add = TRUE, pch = 16)
```

[image: map of NC with 3 points inside cnty Mecklenburg]

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that the problem does not occur on Ubuntu. Tomorrow I will check on Windows to see if I always get a problem with locator() or just with sf plots.

Comment: Hi,I have the same identical problem on windows. Any update?