# Misposition of locator points for a sf map

Tags: r, r-sf, cran

We are still on the problem of calculating distance on a map avoiding the land. We would like to use the 3rd method of this tutorial https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/02/three-ways-to-calculate-distances-in-r/.

To this aim, we use this shapefile:

```
spainurl <- "https://geo.vliz.be/geoserver/wfs?request=getfeature&service=wfs&version=1.0.0&typename=MarineRegions:coasts_subnational&outputformat=SHAPE-ZIP&filter=%3CPropertyIsEqualTo%3E%3CPropertyName%3Emrgid_1%3C%2FPropertyName%3E%3CLiteral%3E3417%3C%2FLiteral%3E%3C%2FPropertyIsEqualTo%3E"
download.file(spainurl, "spain.zip", mode = "wb")
unzip("spain.zip", exdir = "spain", junkpaths = TRUE)

spainCoast_CoteBanyuls <- list.files("spain",
                                     pattern = "shp$",
                                     full.names = TRUE) %>% st_read()
```

We wanted now to put points on this map:

```
plot(spainCoast_CoteBanyuls$geometry, axes = T)
A1 <- locator(1)
print(A1)
points(A1)
```

However the points that is created (place at the red dot) appears somehow misplaced (black point). I really cannot understand why ???

[image]

Even when I do:

```
> spainCoast_CoteBanyuls$geometry
Geometry set for 1 feature 
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 2.778126 ymin: 41.65128 xmax: 3.32476 ymax: 42.43349
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
MULTILINESTRING ((3.185976 41.86163, 3.185129 4...
```

We can see that bounding box min is 2.77. but when we look at the graph we can see that the min is less than 2.5°.

Does someone have a idea?

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Comment: Hi. I think it might be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72771177/is-it-possible-to-use-locator-with-plots-generated-by-sf Are you running that code on MS windows?

Comment: Exact ! I am on ubuntu and my student is on Windows and does not have this problem :D

Comment: So is the opposite for you? It works on Windows and doesn't work on ubuntu?

Comment: Exactly, this is weird !